# Set type to any from a list of classes

Tags: angularjs, typescript, types

I have large list of components and a function that returns a component from that list based on a search query.

The search function looks something like this:

```
export const components = [Comp1, Comp2, Comp3];

export type AnyComponent = Comp1 | Comp2 | Comp3... ;

export function findComponent(id: string): Type<AnyComponent>|undefined {
  return components.find(component => component.id === id);
}
```

Is there a way to avoid listing out my components twice both for the type definition and the list?

Maybe by having a reduction function that returns the list of types in a union or maybe by not even having an AnyComponent and just using the array?

Something that would produce the results similar to what you could expect from this:

```
Type<...components>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a type query to get the type of an item in the `components` array which is exactly the union type you want:

```
export type AnyComponent = typeof components[number]; // The class type

export type AnyComponent = InstanceType<typeof components[number]>; // or the instance type
```

You could use `InstanceType<typeof components[number]>` everywhere, but I suspect having a type alias is nicer

Playground [link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Comp1%7B%20private%20x%3D%2010%7D%0D%0Aclass%20Comp2%7B%20private%20x%3D%2010%7D%0D%0Aclass%20Comp3%7B%20private%20x%3D%2010%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20const%20components%20%3D%20%5BComp1%2C%20Comp2%2C%20Comp3%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20type%20AnyComponent%20%3D%20typeof%20components%5Bnumber%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20type%20Type%3CT%3E%20%3D%20(...args%3A%20any%5B%5D)%20%3D%3E%20T%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20function%20findComponent(id%3A%20string)%3A%20AnyComponent%7Cundefined%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20components.find(component%20%3D%3E%20component.id%20%3D%3D%3D%20id)%3B%0D%0A%7D)

Comment: Brilliant thats exactly what I'm looking for, thanks! Will give you the green tick when stackoverflow allows me to.

Comment: @DustinSilk was playing around with the code a bit more, added an update  and a playground link :)

Comment: That did work to some degree, but I've actually hit a second stumbling block on this topic, maybe you would have some insight into that too?. https://stackoverflow.com/q/50967851/2050141