# Cast object type to Angulars Type<T>

Tags: angularjs, typescript, types

I have a list of components, an AnyComponent type, and a function to find a component:

```
const components = [Comp1, Comp2, Comp3 ...];

type AnyComponent = typeof components[number];

findComponent(id: string): AnyComponent|undefined {
  return components.find(comp => comp.id === id);
}
```

The problem is that findComponent returns this type:

```
typeof Comp1 | typeof Comp2 | typeof Comp3
```

But the next function i need to use (angulars resolveComponentFactory) requires it to be a `Type<AnyComponent>` or `Type<typeof Comp1 | typeof Comp2 | typeof Comp3>`

If i set the return value of findComponent to `Type<AnyComponent>` I get an error saying its not assignable.

However if i change AnyComponent to this:

```
type AnyComponent = Comp1 | Comp2 | Comp3;
```

then only can i set findComponent return value to `Type<AnyComponent>`, and it all works.

The problem with it all working using a union is that I have to declare each component twice and I'm really looking for a way to define them only once.

So is there a way to have findComponent return `Type<AnyComponent>`?

Answer (score 1):

`AnyComponent` contains a union of the class types (ie `typeof Comp1`). `T` in `Type<T>` expects `T` to be the instance type (ie `Comp1`). Fortunately Typescript has `InstanceType<T>` to extract the instance type from a class type.

We might expect we can do `Type<InstanceType<AnyComponent>>` but since the definition of type `new (...args: any[]) => T` this would result in

```
Type<InstanceType<AnyComponent>> == new (...args: any[]) => Comp1 | Comp2 | Comp3
```

which is not assignable from `Comp1`, what we want is to distribute the instance union in a union of `Type<T>` and for this we need a conditional type:

```
// Dummy 
class Comp1 { static id:string; private s: string}
class Comp2 { static id:string; private s: string}
class Comp3 { static id:string; private s: string}
type Type<T> = new (...args: any[]) => T;

const components = [Comp1, Comp2, Comp3];

type AnyComponent = typeof components[number];
// Conditional type to transform the union of instance type into a union of Type<T>
type TypeUnion<T> = T extends any ? Type<T> : never; 

function findComponent(id: string): TypeUnion<InstanceType<AnyComponent>>|undefined {
    return components.find(comp => comp.id === id);
}
```

Comment: Ah okay this makes sense! Thanks for the extra explanation!! Looks like Angular doesn't quite support typescript 2.8 just yet so i may have to wait a while to use the conditional types. (I tried updating it but all my dependencies started falling apart while not yet support the beta versions of angular).
Thanks again!